# How to write an object to the stream?

Tags: node.js, stream

I'm trying to write an object to the stream:

```
const fs = require('fs');

const stream = fs.createWriteStream('index.json', {objectMode: true});
stream.write({"a":1});

stream.end();
```

According to the [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_constructor_new_stream_writable_options), I can do it, passing option `{objectMode: true}`, but I'm getting an error:

```
events.js:182
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: Invalid data
    at WriteStream._write (fs.js:2116:31)
    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:385:12)
    at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:371:5)
    at WriteStream.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:288:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/rostik404/projects/test-project/test-stream.js:8:8)
    at Module._compile (module.js:573:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:584:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:507:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:470:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:462:3)
```

Version of node is `8.4.0`

Comment: Unrelated tip: refer to documentation that matches your package version. Here's the docs for v8.4.0: https://nodejs.org/docs/v8.4.0/api/

Answer (score 5):

`objectMode` only works for streams that support it, and `fs` streams don't (they don't know what to serialize the object *to*).

You can stringify the data before writing it:

```
stream.write(JSON.stringify({"a":1}));
```

Or, possibly, use [`JSONStream`](https://github.com/dominictarr/JSONStream) (however, it depends on your use case if this is useful or not).

Answer (score 2):

You reference to the wrong documentation. 
The options for `createWriteStream` are documented [here](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createwritestream_path_options):

> options < string> | < Object>
>
> - flags < string>
> - encoding < string>
> - fd < integer>
> - mode < integer>
> - autoClose < boolean>
> - start < integer>

The page you are referencing describes the interface, so that when you instantiate an implementation of the interface, you specify whether `stream.write({"a":1});` is a valid operation or not.